# Practical example of Huygens' principle

Tags: optics, visible-light, huygens-principle

Huygens' Principle is the idea that a plane wave traveling through a slit will expand outwards after passing through a slit.

http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/phyopt/huygen.html

I was looking at a photo recently of a forest where rays of light are coming through the leaves (Here is an example of a similar photo)

https://depositphotos.com/193020512/stock-photo-fresh-green-foliage-with-the.html

Are these rays of light around the opening in the tree line actually an example of the wavelets described by Huygens' Principle?  Or is something else at play?

Answer (score 1):

No, the rays are not a diffraction effect.  They are either due to scattering st the lens surface, or due to scatter from light rays passing through a slight fog between the camera and the trees. Probably they are due to lens scatter.  If rotating the camera and shooting the same scene results in the rays rotating to a different angle, it's lens scatter.